# Exec format error when running a jar file as systemd service

Tags: java, operating-system, systemd

I have a problem when running a jar application as a systemd service. I get this error :

```
systemd[30196]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/java_apps/app1/app1.jar: Exec format error
```

but when i run it manually using java -jar command it runs well.

i have verified the permissions of the directories and files, the jar is built using the same java version...

app1.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=APP1 Java Service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=app1_user
ExecStart=/opt/java_apps/app1/app1.jar
StandardError=null
StandardOutput=null
LimitNOFILE=65536
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/jdk-17.0.7+7
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

app1.conf:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.config.location=/opt/java_apps/app1/conf/ \
-Dlogging.config=/opt/java_apps/app1/conf/logback.xml \
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 \
-server -Xms2g \
-Xmx2g \
-Xmn400m \
-XX:MetaspaceSize=256m \
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m \
-XX:+PrintConcurrentLocks -verbosegc -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit -Xlog:gc:/var/log/java_apps/app1/gc-app1-2_%t.log \
-XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/heapdump \
-XX:ErrorFile=/var/log/java_apps/app1/hs_err_%t.log \
-Djdk.tls.maxCertificateChainLength=100 \
-Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/opt/java_apps/snappy"
```

i want a solution to run the app1.jar as a systemd service please.

Comment: `ExecStart='java -jar /opt/java_apps/app1/app1.jar'` Your environment setting will likely be unused, so you might want `ExecStart="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar /opt/java_apps/app1/app1.jar"` but I'm not sure about expansion order. Then there's that .conf file. The contents might have to be part of the environment too

Comment: @g00se, thank you but i have test that also before, it doesn't work

Comment: I can readily believe there could be errors, but I find it hard to believe you get *the same error*

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. Tricky

```
[Unit]
Description=APP1 Java Service
After=syslog.target

[Service]

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/bellsoft-java20-full-amd64"
WorkingDirectory=/opt/java_apps/app1
User=app1_user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" -jar app1.jar
StandardError=null
StandardOutput=null
LimitNOFILE=65536
SuccessExitStatus=143

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Of course, that `StandardError=null` is dangerous as you'll never see why, if it fails. You probably want `StandardError=journal`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding this config to my springboot plugin (in the pom.xml):

```xml
<configuration>
    <executable>true</executable>
</configuration>
```

I rebuilt the application and it runs fine as a systemd service. The issue was that it was not built as executable.

I appreciate your response, [@g00se](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16376827/g00se), but the problem wasn't that.